# Change the comment character in Sublime 2 for a specific syntax

Tags: sublimetext2

Sublime's Haml syntax uses `//` for comments when I hit cmd-/. I would like to override it use `-#` instead. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which Haml package are you using in ST2?

Take a look inside this bundle  `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Rails/Ruby Haml Comments.tmPreferences`  and change the `//` to `-#` i.e.:

Before

```
<string>TM_COMMENT_START</string>
<key>value</key>
<string>// </string>
```

After

```
<string>TM_COMMENT_START</string>
<key>value</key>
<string>-# </string>
```

This works if you are using the HAML bundle that is available via the ST2 package manager

Comment: Thanks! That did it. I wonder if there's a way that wouldn't get reset if or when I get an updated Haml package. I could fork the repo, but that seems excessive.

Comment: This should definitely be the default behavior in sublime! If you fork it, I'll absolutely use it!

Comment: this doesn't seem to work on HTML extended language, any idea why?